# Magento2.2.5 change create account link in top right header

Tags: magento2, xml, magento-2.2.5, header

I want to change the URL of the "create An account" link that is on the top right of the site. I want the link to instead of being  customer/account/create/ I want it to be  customer/account/login

I believe I have to edit the default xml file that is

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Customer/layout
```

here is the file just not sure how to edit it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer" template="account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <move element="header" destination="header.links" before="-"/>
    <move element="register-link" destination="header.links"/>
    <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>
    <move element="authorization-link" destination="top.links" after="-"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change class of block `register-link` to `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link`

Now you can pass the parameter `path` to change link

So your final `default.xml` should look like this:

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">customer/account/login</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

    ....
    ....
  </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove existing `Create an Account` link and add a custom link. You need to edit following file:

> mage2Root/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Add below code inside `body` tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="add-new-header-link">
        <arguments>
             <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account@</argument>
             <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">customer/account/login</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

If needed you can use `after`,`before` for adjust position of link.

Hope above will help!

Comment: We don't need to remove existing `register-link` link

Comment: Yes, you are right! great..